# Qooxdoo mobile: multiple selection in form

Tags: mobile, qooxdoo

I am working on a Qooxdoo mobile application using the latest 2.1 release.

I have a requirement for a form with a mutliple selection inline. I did not find a multiselect in the mobile API docs. Does it exist?

Alternatively I could make my own widget with label and option checkboxes on the same line. Are there any examples out there to get started?

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite/extend the FormRenderer "Single" for this purpose.

There you can add the widgets in one single line, if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer.

Just took qx.ui.mobile.form.CheckBox as a template and extended it to show multiple values + checkboxes. Would have liked to have seen some pointers in the docs, but I could also have dug a bit deeper in the SC.